# Random numbers are generated twice when verifying email

Tags: php, email-verification

I'm new to PHP. I'm currently doing an email validation. My code is supposed to generate a random number, send to user via email and verify it when user enters.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

session_start();

// initializing variables
$email = $_SESSION ['email'];
$user_code = "";
$errors = array();

// generate a four digit random number
$gen_code = strval (rand (10000, 99999));

// send code to user email

// connect to the database
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'register');

// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['email_confirm'])) {

  // receive all input values from the form
  $user_code = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['code']);

  // check whether both codes match
  if ($user_code != $gen_code) { array_push($errors, "The codes do not match"); }
  else {
    // set isConfirmed == true
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $query = "UPDATE user_database SET isConfirmed = true WHERE email = '$email'";
        mysqli_query($db, $query);
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        header('location: user_details.php');
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Here `email_confirm` is the name of my submit button and `code` is the name of text box.

It all works fine when page is first loaded. I get an email with a random integer.

Problem starts when I click my submit button. I receive another email with different number and the number I already entered is not equal to the one I received from email.

Please help

Comment: is that all your code, it sends no email

Comment: i didn't include email sending logic because the code would be large. since the logic is working i omitted it

Comment: well, you say it's sending an email when it shouldn't, so it sounds like the logic is not working. anyway, I can't help without the code.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a simpler and an experimental application, you should store gen_code in this session soon after its sent to the user confirmation email. Otherwise, store the code in db and retrieve it when your application receives email confirm POST request and compare the code that was sent by the user against the session or db wherever you'd stored it.

```
if (isset($_POST['email_confirm'])) { 
    // receive all input values from the form
    $code = $_SESSION['gen_code']; // in case you would wish to store and retrieve code from db, replace this code with one which retrieved from db by email id... SELECT code from user where email=$email
    $user_code = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['code']);
    // check whether both codes match
    if ($user_code != $code) { 
        array_push($errors, "The codes do not match");
    } else {
        if (count($errors) == 0) {
            $query = "UPDATE user_database SET isConfirmed = true WHERE email = '$email'"; 
            mysqli_query($db, $query);
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            header('location: user_details.php');
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: still not working. I'm getting Notice: Undefined index: gen_code

Comment: When I send confirmation mail to the user, u need to store the gen code in either session or db. $_SESSION['gen_code'] = gen_code;